# Assuming that a symbol has an integer value in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I believe that the following should evaluate to 1, but it doesn't. Any hints on how to make it work?

```
n = Symbol('n')
with assuming(Q.integer(n)):
    print(cos(2*pi*n))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
>>> cos(2*pi*n) 
1
>>> sin(2*pi*n) 
0
```

Comment: Interestingly, `cos(pi*n)` produces `(-1)**n`.